# Send physical check in US funds from India

Tags: india, check

What is best way to get a check in US funds (preferably through SBI)  which is to be mailed to US address later?

Comment: Have you tried contacting SBI by e-mail or calling them or even (shudders!) visiting your SBI office in person to find out if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit the main branch of any leading bank and ask for foreign currency demand draft denominated in USD.

Comment: Ah, these modern times. In 1967-68, it was necessary for the bank to get permission from the Reserve Bank of India to issue such demand drafts (for paying application fees for graduate school admission).